Finding the 123ʳᵈ Number in a Sequence After Removing Multiples of 5 or 7
I'm working on a problem involving a sequence of the first 300 positive integers, from 1 to 300. However, I need to find the 123ʳᵈ number in the sequence after removing all numbers that are divisible by either 5 or 7.
To calculate the number of integers divisible by 5, I used the formula:
$$\frac{300}{5}=60$$
To calculate the number of integers divisible by 7, I used the formula:
$$\frac{300}{7}=42$$
​
Considering the numbers divisible by both 5 and 7 (which is 35), I calculated the number of integers divisible by 35 as
$$\frac{300}{35}=8$$
Then, to find the total number of integers remaining after removing those divisible by either 5 or 7, I subtracted the total number of integers divisible by 5 and 7 from 300, and added back the number of integers divisible by both 5 and 7:
$$300 - 60 - 42 + 8 = 206$$
Now, to find the 123ʳᵈ number in the remaining sequence of 206 integers, should I count it manually, one by one, from the beginning of the sequence? Or is there a more efficient or systematic approach to identify the 123ʳᵈ number without manually counting each number?
Any guidance, hints, or strategies on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance for your assistance.

It may help to take $5\times7=35$ numbers at a time

Hint: exploit periodicity: the nonremoved naturals $,n,$ are precisely those coprime to $5$ and $7$, which, by Euclid, is equivalent to being coprime to $35$. But $n$ is coprime to $35!\iff! n+35$ is coprime to $35,,$ so the same number of nonremoved elements appear in each interval $,[35k, 35(k!+!1)),,$ that number being $,\phi(5\cdot 7) = 4\cdot 6 = 24,,$ where $,\phi  $ = Euler totient function. $\ \ $

@BillDubuque:  did you mean $(35k,35(k+1)]?$

@J.W.T Either way works, but since OP starts at $1$ it is indeed more convenient to start our period at $1$ too. $\ \ $

In the first $35$ positive integers, you are going remove $11$ of them because they are divisible by $5$ or $7$ or both, leaving $24$ integers.  Similarly with the next $35$ positive integers, and so on.
Since $123=5\times 24+3$, your answer is going to be the third number left after five groups of $35$, i.e. after $5\times 35=175$, and since $175$ is a multiple of $5$ and $7$, this will be $178$.
